# How to change the color of text highlighting in Preview using a shortcut?

Tags: macos, preview, color, shortcut

I need to highlight/underline a lot of text and tend to use specific colors for different things. Accessing via the dropdown menu in **Preview** is very slow, does any one know a way to change the color of highlighting/underlining by pressing a shortcut?

I'm using Mavericks.

Comment: Does Command + T work for you to pop-up the font-menu?

Answer (score 1):

As you probably know the Preview does not have the short cut for that function.

Here is the [list](http://mac.keyboard-shortcuts.eu/en/preview/) of shortcuts that Preview does has.

And many other OS applications shortcuts.

[image: shortucts]

Comment: How did you get that list?